# I want to Show Data in Following Manner... by using Single SQL or Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have two table. Parent and child. I want to make a query to show parent and child data. currently i am using join command to relate both parent and child table. see the attached image where i explained the issue:

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved and dont post images.Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table t1
(
id int
)

insert into t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT
    ParentData =  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ParentData ORDER BY c.ChildData) = 1 THEN p.ParentData ELSE '' END,
    <other columns>...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partition:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER
 (
     PARTITION BY SalesHeadColumn
     ORDER BY SalesDetailColumn
 ) AS DuplicateHeads
```

After you have a query incorporating this into your select statement, you can surround it by an over-select and add a case statement so that it blanks out column A if DuplicateHeads is not equal to 1.

Comment: Can you please write  sample query including this.... consider my tables